# No Recommended Software menu after updating and upgrading

Tags: update, raspberry-pi-os

I'm a beginner using a Raspberry Pi 3. I ran the commands, sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, rebooted and logged back in and there is no menu for Recommended Software.
I also ran the command sudo apt-get install rp-prefapps because I read that it might solve the problem but I received the error message E: Unable to locate package rp-prefapps
Has anyone heard of this issue before?